# How to use JavaScript to put image src into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put image src into my code.
This is my JavaScript code so far:

```
<script>
    function images(){
        var randomizer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5)
        var pictures =["images1.jpg","images2","images3.jpg","images4.png","images5.jpg"]
    }
</script>
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
<img  id = "bubbles" src="images1.jpg" width="20%" alt = "pics">
<img id = "bubbles2" src="images2.jpg" width="20%" alt= "pics">
```

The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to put the arrayed string into the src.

Comment: side note : recommend not to have spaces around `=`

Comment: Are you hoping to generate the image tags with the javascript array images? Or would you like to update the same image tag with a random image at a set interval? What is your aim?

Comment: i am trying to like update the value of the src so it will be a random image from the array every time it loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the src attribute of an image tag can't take in an array of images. You'll need a separate image tag for your photos.

```
var pictures = ["images1.jpg", "images2", "images3.jpg", "images4.png", "images5.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    var imgEl = document.getElementById("bubbles");
    imgEl.setAttribute("src", imEl[i]);
}
```

The above code will update the `src` attribute with the images in the array. However, this will probably so quick you'll only see the last one. You would need to figure out a timing mechanism or integrate your random number function to chose a random image.

**Using Math.random()**

```
var pictures = ["images1.jpg", "images2", "images3.jpg", "images4.png", "images5.jpg"];
var randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var imgEl = document.getElementById("bubbles");
imgEl.setAttribute("src", imEl[randomizer]);
```